# How to use Matlab to detected cells that are of different shapes

Tags: image, matlab, hough-transform

I am using MATLAB in order to analyse cell images. At the moment, I am able to detected and measure circular cells only (image attached). Is there a way, I can detect the other cells and measure them? Perhaps, by adding an outline to all the cells and then measuring?

Code so far:

```
tic
close all
clear all
dir = 'C:\Users\CBE user 70\Google Drive\Gloria - PhD\PhD Thesis\Chapter 4 - DS coculture\Pictures\DSHALO MBB\16MARCH\';
FileName = 'DH1L116march(2).JPG';
Pixel2MicroMeterRatio = 6;
HistBinEdges = [5:1:25 ];

vi = 0.05;  % vertical increase in sublpot size (normalized)
hi = 0.08;  % horizontal increase in sublpot size (normalized)
i = imread([dir,FileName]);
i2 = i(:,:,3);
i2= imadjust(i2);
% increase imfindcircles from [11 50] to [5 99], as the cells here are
% larger here 

[CircCenter, CircRadii] = imfindcircles(i2,[5 99],'ObjectPolarity','dark');
NumOfCells = length(CircRadii);

sp(1) = subplot(2,2,1);
imshow(i)

sp(2) = subplot(2,2,2);
imshow(i2)
hold on
c=viscircles(CircCenter, CircRadii,'EdgeColor','r','linewidth',1,'linestyle',':');
c.Children(2).Visible = 'off';
for i=1:NumOfCells
    text(CircCenter(i,1),CircCenter(i,2),num2str(i),'fontsize',6,'color','c','HorizontalAlignment','center','VerticalAlignment','middle')
end
```

[image]

Comment: you should avoid using spaces in your file_directories, it freaks some people out

Comment: It was one of the main topics in my master thesis, so I cannot give a brief and always working answer. The common plan is 1) flatter or subtract background (i.e. by rolling ball filter); 2) find markers that surely belong to object and background; 3) perform segmentation. For brightfield images if acquired properly and NA < 0.8, magnification x10-x40, watershed is usually sufficient. For high NA, phase contrast, DIC and fluorescence you should spend some time choosing segmentation method that works

Comment: If you have a good dataset you can also try some machine/deep learning algorithm: for example => http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/cell_detection/

Comment: Hello, thanks for the tips. I managed to sort the data out.